# How to scroll flat list without touch effect

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, mobile-development

I am new in react native, I have used `FlatList` which has `ListItem` as component:

```html
 <FlatList
       style={styles.container}
       data={items}
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
         <ListItem
           title={item.title}
           onPress={() => console.log("this is pressed", item.id)}
           )}
         />
       )}
       keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      
     />
```

Everything is working fine only the
Problem is: when user scrolls the view i.e `FlatList` the point where finger is pressed that component shows `touch` effect. I want `touch` effect happened only when that element is pressed not when is scrolled. Is there any way to solve this?

1. Code for `ListItem`

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import { AppText } from "./AppText";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";

function ListItem({title,onPress}) {
  return (
    <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={[{ backgroundColor }, styles.container]}>
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            {title && <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>}
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 10,
  },
  textContainer: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "900",
  },
});

export default ListItem;
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code from the ListItem Component?

Comment: @Arbnor Yes I have added it.

Comment: It isn't easy to prevent that. Maybe you can work with the disabled prop of the touchable and set it always to true when you are scrolling. I think then all UI interactions with the listitem will be disabled.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#disabled